# Flip characters separately in string

Tags: ios, transform, nsattributedstring, core-text

I have a special requirement in my IOS app, I want to flip every characters in a string, the following picture is the input and final result I want.

[image]

Currently I have tried with UIFont, I use setTransform method, but this applies to the context which flip the entire string. Then I try to use NSAttributedString since it can apply special effect to a given range in the text. I go through all the attributes in this [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688) under Constants section, but it seems there is no such attribute.

Is that possible to create context for each character in a string? How can I manage the spaces between characters if this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reverse the string and then flip it.

I.e.

ABCD -> DCBA -> the flipped image you want.

Just use the transform like you did before but reverse the string first.

Comment: who voted this up? This does not really solve the problem because zdd wants to flip only parts of the string. In his image example, for example, A is not flipped, but BCD is flipped. You *can* mirror a string with `transform`, you don't have to reverse it first.

Comment: @Michael the only reason that A is not flipped is because it is symmetrical. Lol! I think you are mistaking which direction the flip is. It is not top-to-bottom but left-to-right. Kindly remove the down vote. Thanks.

Comment: This almost solve my problem, but if there is a multiple line string, the order was incorrect after reverse and flip. I mean the first letter will in the last line. This is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's a bit hard...

First, split the string into parts that should be upside-down, and parts that should be normal. E.g. you may want to split "Hello world!" and "world" should be upside down. So you have "Hello ", "world", "!". You can always make it so that the first string is normal: E.g. if you want to have "Hello" upside-down and the rest of the string normal, the list would be "", "Hello", " world!".

For each of the strings create a `UILabel`. Call `-sizeToFit` on each of them. Place them next to each other. Set the `transform` property for each UILabel that should be upside down (i.e. for every second `UILabel`) to the *appropriate value*.

You may wrap all of the UILabels so created into a container view, or even create a UIView subclass that hides all the implementation details (recommended).

Done.

Comment: will give a try to your suggestion later.